# How to add custom filters to Google Reporting API V4 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics

I've currently got a Python script which outputs a chunk of data based on Date, City, Latitude & Longitude.

I've tried to implement ga:pagePath in order to filter this data and only show results on '/example'. However, it does not accept this request in the dimensions part of the code.

How would I implement this as a custom filter in order to refine the data dump the API produces.

Also, how would I modify the code at the bottom of the script which formats the data to include this new filter?

Are there any documents out there which detail how to add filters into the api v4 via python, ideally in a similar fashion to how the Query Explorer adds in filters

Here is the code:

```
import httplib2 as lib2
from oauth2client import client


from googleapiclient.discovery import build as google_build


import pandas
import numpy
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

access_token = "ya29.GlsMBiqWA-CNAqOvGwDimYyzG9svM_kkjxTIyMEPWXDFrsYwOcJwWUWTWUrT9hD0prWp5UU4CI6ZHLeIyh2k-QsfToLWrmPNBmO9mg7OGAozGFlDGNniaZ6qiK7o"
refresh_token = "1/H6jExOHvrGS6-TEbDG1EQDIy1_CGFq-UDbVqI_Du9P0"
client_id = "61721534450-4rsaodi636nvb02pmg9k5ck4nkk5epgq.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret = "pORiELmRxdWotyDhllOAFvcO"


token_uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'


token_expiry = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)


user_agent = 'my-user-agent/1.0'


credentials = client.GoogleCredentials(access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token,
                                       client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
                                       token_uri=token_uri, token_expiry=token_expiry,
                                       user_agent=user_agent)


http = lib2.Http()


authorized = credentials.authorize(http)


api_name = 'analyticsreporting'
api_version = 'v4'


api_client = google_build(serviceName=api_name, version=api_version, http=authorized)
sample_request = {
      'viewId': '6690355',
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
      },
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},{'name': 'ga:city'}, {'name': 'ga:latitude'},{'name': 'ga:longitude'},{'name': 'ga:pagePath'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
    }

response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': sample_request
      }).execute()
print(response)

def prase_response(report):

    """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""

    result_list = []


    data_csv = []
    data_csv2 = []


    header_row = []


    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])


    for dheader in dimensionHeaders:
        header_row.append(dheader)
    for mheader in metricHeaders:
        header_row.append(mheader['name'])


    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    for row in rows:
        row_temp = []
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        metrics = row.get('metrics', [])
        for d in dimensions:
            row_temp.append(d)
        for m in metrics[0]['values']:
            row_temp.append(m)
            data_csv.append(row_temp)


        if len(metrics) == 2:
            row_temp2 = []
            for d in dimensions:
                row_temp2.append(d)
            for m in metrics[1]['values']:
                row_temp2.append(m)
            data_csv2.append(row_temp2)


    result_df = pandas.DataFrame(data_csv, columns=header_row)
    result_list.append(result_df)
    if data_csv2 != []:
        result_list.append(pandas.DataFrame(data_csv2, columns=header_row))

    return result_list

response_data = response.get('reports', [])[0]
print(prase_response(response_data)[0])

prase_response(response_data)[0].to_csv('example.csv')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `dimensionFilterClauses` to your `sample_request`? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#filtering_2